# Text is not readable in JSon response

Tags: java, android, json

[image: Text is readable in sources but not above]

I am trying to display string under pageContent tag in JSON object received from URL:
http://www.pratilipi.com/api.pratilipi/pratilipi/content?pratilipiId=4843865324388352

Problem is that text is not in readable format, it is readable when inspected in browser, under sources. How can I get similar results in java.

Comment: Content language is Hindi and on server UTF-8 character encoding is set.

Comment: Maybe set the encoding in the response header?